# Android websocket client closing connection with error java.io.EOFException on server onError event , once received first message from server

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, websocket

I am beginner to android. I need help on below android websocket client to long run websocket session.

Java Spring boot WebSocket server running on Desktop with

For Java websocket Server using below dependency,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Server sample code:**

```
@Component
@ServerEndpoint("/dialer")
public class WSServer {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        // Get session and WebSocket connection
        System.out.println("Connected");
        
        //session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Data Ok");
        
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Message recieved");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Session Closed");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
        
        System.out.println("Session Exception "+throwable.getMessage());
    }
}
```

for Android WebSocket client using below dependency,

```
implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0'
```

Android Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private JWebSocketClient client;
    private JWebSocketClientService.JWebSocketClientBinder binder;
    private JWebSocketClientService jWebSClientService;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            //Service and activity bound successfully
            Log.e("mainactivity", "service and activity bound successfully");
            binder = (JWebSocketClientService.JWebSocketClientBinder) iBinder;
            jWebSClientService = binder.getService();
            client = jWebSClientService.client;
            try {
                jWebSClientService.connectToWS();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            //Service and activity disconnection
            Log.e("mainactivity", "service and activity disconnected successfully");
        }
    };

    EditText edtPhoneNo;
    TextView lblinfo;
    private WebSocket ws =null;
    private WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
    public static final String TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME";
    private static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhoneNumber);
        lblinfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblinfo);
        bindService();
        
    }
......
}
```

**JWebSocketClient.java**

```
public class JWebSocketClient extends WebSocketClient {

    public JWebSocketClient(URI serverUri) {
        super(serverUri, new Draft_6455());
    }
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {

        Log.e("JWebSocketClient", "onOpen()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        Log.e("JWebSocketClient", "onMessage()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        Log.e("JWebSocketClient", "onClose()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("JWebSocketClient", "onError()");
    }

}
```

Using below background service to keep long running,

JWebSocketClientService.java

```
public class JWebSocketClientService extends Service {

    private  URI uri;
    public  JWebSocketClient client;
    private JWebSocketClientBinder mBinder = new JWebSocketClientBinder();

    //For communication between activity and service
    class JWebSocketClientBinder extends Binder {
        public JWebSocketClientService getService() {
            return JWebSocketClientService.this;
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    
    public void connectToWS() throws InterruptedException {

        Log.i("websocket", "connectToWS() called.");
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws://{ip:port}/dialer");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        client = new JWebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
                Log.i("websocket", "connected to server.");
                client.send("connect:::TESTKEY");
                //webSocketClient.send("alert:::HI");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {

                Log.i("websocket", message);
                Log.i("websocket", "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
                Log.i("websocket", "closed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception ex) {

                Log.i("websocket" , "error : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        };
        try {
            client.connectBlocking();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Android client establishing connection with Server and  client onMessage () receiving 1st message from Sever then immediately receiving onError() event on Server side with error **Java.io.EOFException**.

Please help me on this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working. Issue is due to misuse of Android studio.

Comment: What do you mean by misuse of Android studio @balaji

Comment: What is the solution?